# Dismissing a presentedVC.swift from an ObjC VC

Tags: swift, delegates, presentmodalviewcontroller

**Scenario:**

Host `VC` is an **Objective-C** `UIViewController` ("`BLSTimelineViewController`").

Presented Controller is a Swift `UIViewController`.

I'm trying to dismissed the **Swift VC**.

Initially I tried the following:

Header link:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "BLSTimelineViewController.h"
```

**Objective-C** Source:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Bliss" bundle:nil];
    LoginViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginVC"];
    controller.sendingVC = self;

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

**Swift Popup**:

```
...

import Foundation
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    var sendingVC:BLSTimelineViewController?

    // MARK: - Action functions

    @IBAction func loginAction(sender: UIButton) {

            sendingVC.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

I get the following compiler error:
[image]
What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Note the question mark at the end. You need to unwrap the optional.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code doesn't compile -- have you actually included `BLSTimelineViewController.h` in your ObjC-to-Swift bridging header?

Updated: Your new error is "BLSTimeViewController? does not have a member named..." The question mark indicates that you're not looking at the actual instance of the class, but a wrapper. To unwrap it, add !, for example:

`sendingVC!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(...)`

Note that by using ! you're asserting that the value isn't nil -- your code will crash on this line if `sendingVC` happens to be nil. To deal with it, make sure it isn't nil, or add a nil check.

Please read this post to learn more about unwrapping: https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-06-20-interesting-swift-features.html

Comment: I added the Objective-C header into the bridge header. 
It appears that Swift 'sees' the Objective-C class. But...  
Now I get the complaint that BLSTimelineViewController doesn't have the method requested; which is a UIViewController method.